# Web Scraping using Beautifulsoup get text from <span> inside <div>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code that scrapes real estate data.
Part of the code is the following:

```
for sqm in soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-view real-estates'}).find_all('div', {'class': 'inline-group'}):
    sqm_value = sqm.get_text()
    sqm_area.append(sqm_value)
```

So far I get a big chunk of the code, but I am only interested in the area.
The problem with that is that sometimes in the description where the sq.m. value is there are either 1 or 2 commas beforehand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFt3c.png

This is the link to the site from where I try to scrape the data:
https://www.imoti.net/bg/obiavi/r/prodava/bulgaria/?page=1&sid=iXMpXe

I am looking for this value only (I can remove the 'м' from the string).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRbOf.png

Any ideas on how I can extend my code to get the sq.m. value?

Comment: you can `split(",")` to get list and use `[-1]` to get last value from list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `split` text on `,` to get list. And use `[-1]` to get last element from this list

```
sqm_value.split(",")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select 2nd `<span>` in that's in `<h3>` which is in `<div>` with class `inline-group` using `select('h3 > span:nth-child(2)')`.